# Send metrics query on AWS AMP

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus

I am using AWS Managed Prometheus service and setup a Prometheus server on my EKS cluster to collect and write metrics on my AMP workspace, using the helm chart, as per tutorial from AWS. All works fine, I am also connecting to a cluster run Grafana and I can see the metrics no problem.

However, my use case is to query metrics from my web application which runs on the cluster and to display the said metrics using my own diagram widgets. In other words, I don't want to use Grafana.

So I was thinking to use the AWS SDK (Java in my case, https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/amp/model/package-summary.html), which works fine (I can list my workspaces etc...), except it doesn't have any method for querying metrics!?

The documentation indeed mentions that this is not out of the box (!) and basically redirects to Grafana...

This seems fairly odd to me as the basic use case would be to run some queries no? Am I missing something here? do I need to create my own HTTP requests for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I ended up doing the query manually, creating an SdkHttpFullRequest and using an AWS4Signer to sign it. Works OK but I wonder why it couldn't be included in the SDK directly... The only gotcha was to make sure to specify the "aps" for the signing name in the Aws4SignerParams creation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to do this in go, below is a working example.

It uses `QueryMetrics` http endpoint of [Amazon Managed Prometheus API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-APIReference.html#AMP-APIReference-QueryMetrics). The request must be signed with SIGV4 signing protocol in which I am using AWS sdk  to simplify the process.

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "testing"
    "time"

    signer "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/signer/v4"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
)

func Test__QueryMetricsFromAMP(t *testing.T) {
    query := `count(kube_node_info{})`
    res, err := queryMetrics(query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}

func queryMetrics(q string) ([]byte, error) {
    // You must set your login credentials/configs as environment variables first
    // or create aws.Config the way you like

    // 1. Get AWS credentials for signing the request
    awsConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    creds, err := awsConfig.Credentials.Retrieve(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // 2. Prepare the http request to AMP
    url := "https://aps-workspaces.YOUR_AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/workspaces/YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID/api/v1/query?query=" + q
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // 3. Sign the request
    s := signer.NewSigner()
    err = s.SignHTTP(context.TODO(), creds, req, emptyStringHash(), "aps", "YOUR_AWS_REGION", time.Now().UTC())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // 4. Send the request
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // 5. Read the response body
    return io.ReadAll(res.Body)
}

func emptyStringHash() string {
    x := sha256.New()
    return hex.EncodeToString(x.Sum(nil)) // e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
}
```